# How to fire dropdownlist's SelectedIndexChanged without postback?

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

I've got a DropDownList on my page databound to a query from my database (Databinding is set up only in my .aspx file, not in codebehind). Next to it I have a second DDL that gets populated from the SelectedIndexChanged function of the first one. This works, but only when AutoPostback is set to true.

Is there a way to fire the SelectedIndexChanged event or manually call this function in my codebehind without having to reload the page every time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would put the DDLs inside an AJAX `UpdatePanel` so it only updates that part of the page instead of a full page reload.

Answer (score 2):

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
            Your Stuff with OnSelectedIndexChanged in codebehind
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Rul easy

Answer (score 0):

Attach to the `<select />` element's `onChange` event a JavaScript function, and do an AJAX request to a webservice.